# Question about finding volume using integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is:

Find the volume of the solid whose base is a circle $x^2 + y^2 = 81$ and the cross sections perpendicular to the $x-axis$ are triangles whose height and base are equal.

Now what the question is asking for is to find the Area of the vertical cross section $A$ at the level $x=2$

I've tried a few things but I just can't seem to get it right... any suggestions?

Comment: Draw a picture of the circle. Area of a triangle is $1/2$ times the base times the height. At $x=2$, we have $y^2=77$. The base is $2\sqrt{77}$. Continue.

Comment: How? base is circle and cross sections perpendicular to x-axis are triangles